# search bar coming below navigation bar

Tags: html, css

The search bar should be inside the navigation bar just right to XYZ but it comes below the navigation bar.What should be done?

```
<div id="bar" class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="main.php">XYZ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#bar{
    min-width: 800px;
    background-color: #563d7c;  
    width:100%; 
    height:42px;    
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px #888888;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just float the logo to the left.

`#logo{float:left;}`

Comment: The button still hangs below.

Comment: To fix that... If the button doesn't need to be in a div but still needs the class attached to the div then change the div to a span.  Or apply a float: left; to the div the button is in.

Comment: however the search bar is not exactly coming in center of the bar HEIGHTWISE.How can I do that?

Comment: you can apply a padding to the #bar element to get the content centered.  If don't want everything centered then you can add a top and bottom margin to .col-xs-5.  But you will need to subtract from the height you have set for #bar.  There are plenty of sites out there that explain how padding margins work; I would suggest giving them a look over.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to be done is wrap `.col-xs-5` into `div.row`.

Besides that, try to attach jsfiddle demo for better demonstration of an issue next time.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.